Bochner-Sobolev spaces with second time derivative and embeddings
In the weak theory of evolution PDEs, the Bochner-Sobolev spaces are frequently used. For $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $X,Y$ banach spaces, we define these spaces as
$$W^{1,p,q}(a,b,X,Y) = \left\{v, \  \text{  such that  } \ \  v \in L^p(a,b;X) \ \text{ and } \ \frac{d}{dt} v \in L^q(a,b;Y) \right\}.$$
The Aubin-Lions lemma then gives compact embedding results given certain conditions are met for $X, Y$ and $p,q$.
My question is what about such spaces with higher time derivative order? For example we can define
$$W^{2,p,q,l}(a,b,X,Y,Z) = \left\{v, \  \text{  such that  } \ \  v \in L^p(a,b;X) \ \text{ and } \ \frac{d}{dt} v \in L^q(a,b;Y) \ \text{ and } \ \frac{d^2}{dt^2} v \in L^l(a,b;Z) \right\}.$$
This definition is given in Roubíček's Nonlinear PDEs With Applications for $p= \infty$ (formula (7.4)) but I cannot find any embedding results mentioned there.
Even more general, what about space for time derivatives of order $k$?
Any references would be appreciated!

One reference is: ``Compact embeddings of vector-valued Sobolev and Besov spaces" by H. Amann, see https://hrcak.srce.hr/file/7912 or http://user.math.uzh.ch/amann/files/cevvss.pdf

@daw I will check that. Thank you!
